# Jquery submit trim issue

Tags: jquery

I have the following html, and want to trim the **forgot-password-email-address** input value before submitting.

```
<form action="passwordpost/" method="post" id="forgot-password-form">

                    <label for="username">Email Address</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="forgot-password-email-address" class="required" name="email" value=""><br/><br/>

                    <button type="submit" title="Find" class="form-button button forgotpasswordpost" name="submit" id="forgotpasswordpost-btn" style="float:right;">
                        <span><span>Send My Password</span></span>
                    </button>                       
            </form>
```

The jQuery I have for this is below, yet it does not submit the form with the trimmed input. It submits, but with whitespace still in place.

```
$J("#forgot-password-form").submit(function(event){
    $J("#forgot-password-email-address").val().trim();
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val()` and `trim()` both return strings, they don't modify strings. You need to reset the value:

```
var $field = $J("#forgot-password-email-address");

$field.val($field.val().trim());
```

Using the callback version, as undefined suggested, may be better here:

```
$J("#forgot-password-email-address").val(function(idx, value) {
    return value.trim();
    //return $.trim(value); // could also use jQuery's trim()
});
```

Comment: Using `.val()`  callback function seems to be useful here. `$field.val(function(_, oldVal) { return $.trim(oldVal) })`.

Comment: Thanks very much - code works of course, but the explanation is really helpful for a jQuery beginner like me. Will mark as answer in 5 mins once I can.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$J("#forgot-password-email-address").val($J("#forgot-password-email-address").val().trim());
```

Your code is only *trimming* the value of the input but not setting it to the element.

A small version of it:

```
var el = $J("#forgot-password-email-address");
el.val(el.val().trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is submitting the value in the textbox, update it's value

```
$J("#forgot-password-email-address").val($J("#forgot-password-email-address").val().trim());
```

You were not updating the value of the textbox previously.

Comment: please replace : trim => trim()

Comment: @user3041160 Done and I beg forgiveness!